# Mysql query working from command line but only half working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

**1.owners**
id
firstname
lastname

**2.product**
id
id2
id3
item

```
SELECT * FROM owners LEFT JOIN product ON product.id=owners.id where firstname='Jezebel';
```

Works fine from the command line returning all relevant items from owners and product but using the following PHP

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM owners LEFT JOIN product ON product.id=owners.id where firstname='".$_POST['fname']."'")
```

only returns results from the table owners.

I have googled extensively and don't see anyone else with this problem.

Comment: Let's just hope their first name isn't Bobby Tables http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: let's make sure your $_POST value doesn't have white space. So, add trim($_POST['fname'])

Comment: Make sure the query that's being dynamically generated by PHP is what it should be by echoing it: echo "SELECT * FROM owners LEFT JOIN product ON product.id=owners.id where firstname='".$_POST['fname']."'";

Comment: echo "SELECT * FROM owners LEFT JOIN product ON product.id=owners.id where firstname='".$_POST['fname']."'"; gives this result gives this result obviously PHP is not generating the query expected. SELECT * FROM owners LEFT JOIN product ON product.id=owners.id where firstname='John'57585911011111260. It is appending the id3 numbers to the end of the query in this case the numbers 57 58 59 110 111 112 60

Answer (score 0):

```
$fname= $_POST['fname'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM owners LEFT JOIN product ON product.id=owners.id where firstname='$fname'")
```

Comment: No that doesn't change anything.
| 53 | Jezebel

Comment: @user2223659 trying adding `trim($_POST['fname'])` to your $_POST variable.

Comment: can you please echo only the query. and paste the output here.

Answer (score 0):

First, make your query similar to this

```
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM owners LEFT JOIN product ON product.id=owners.id where firstname='%s'",mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fname'])));
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

and let me know the result so I can update this answer.

Comment: array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "53" ["firstname"]=> string(7) "Jezebel" ["middlename"]=> string(0) "" ["lastname"]=> string(0) "" ["id2"]=> string(1) "0" ["id3"]=> string(2) "53" ["item"]=> string(15) "Material" }

Comment: @user2223659 That's working. remove the var_dump() and continue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You have two table which match on autoincrement column `id`?

However, try this?

```
SELECT tb1.id, tb1. firstname, tb1.lastname, tb2.id, tb2.id2, tb2.id3, tb2.item FROM owners AS tb1 LEFT JOIN product AS tb2 ON tb2.id=tb1.id where tb1.firstname=$fname
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error. It was nothing to do with the select statement. I had a typo in the display code. It should have been like this

```
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['id3'];
```

But was like this instead

```
echo "</td></td>"; 
echo $row['id3'];
```

Thank you all for your help.